# adb disable-verity - NOT Found

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, adb, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying DUT debugging using adb in my ubuntu machine 20+.
when I try to disable-verity, I am getting the following error "/system/bin/sh disable-verity not found"
I tried reinstalling adb again , and I am running to the same issue.
I ran the DUT in different windows setups, it is running fine though
Anything I am missing?

Another thing I noted is: running just adb is giving segmentation fault, however running adb with other arguements is running fine. ie adb devices

Comment: Are you trying to execute the command on an emulator or a physical device. Those commands usually only work for the emulator or devices with a debug ROM installed.

Comment: I got it worked after downgrading adb, Thanks @robert anyway